# XML Module Parsing Differences Between 2.7.6 and 2.7.3 in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am using this this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrPZza_vZ3w) to go through some concepts of Python, however, I ran into this problem trying to use this line of a code in 2.76. Dave is using 2.73 at the 53 minute part of the video in the monitor.py file.

I am using this line of code to try to fix an error...

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
```

As oppose to

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
```

(which is what is used in the video in python 2.7.3)

however it doesn't work when I use it. I get this error instead.

```
   PS C:\python27> python monitor.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "monitor.py", line 28, in <module>
        monitor()
      File "monitor.py", line 15, in monitor
       doc = parse(u)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
       tree.parse(source, parser)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
       parser.feed(data)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
        self._raiseerror(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
        raise err
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &nbsp;: line 50, column 47
```

What import line of code should I write and why? I have tried 'as' and 'import'

Here is the  code that I am using.

```
#monitor.py
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

candidates = ['4131','4163','4132']
daves_latitude = 41.980262


def distance(lat1, lat2):
    'Return distance in miles between two lats'
    return 69*(lat1 - lat2)

def monitor():
    u = urllib.urlopen('http://ctabustracker.com/bustime/mapgetBusesForRoute.jsp?route=22')
    doc = parse(u)
    for bus in doc.findall('bus'):
        busid = bus.findtext('id')
        if busid in candidates:
            lat = float(bus.findtext('lat'))
            dis = distance(lat, daves_latitude)
            print busid, dis, 'miles'
        print '-'*10


import time

while True:
    monitor()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Is this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744945/parse-xml-with-xhtml-entities

Answer (score 0):

```
#XXX INCORRECT, DO NOT USE IT
import xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
```

The error `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &nbsp` is not related to how you import `ElementTree` module in any way. The behaviour is the same in Python 2.7.6 and 2.7.3.

[@karthikr linked to the question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277651/xml-module-parsing-differences-between-2-7-6-and-2-7-3-in-python/22277697#comment33842144_22277651) that explains the issue: `&nbsp;` is not defined for xml by default, see [Parse XML with (X)HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14744945/4279).

Comment: When I use that I get an invalid syntax error on line 3.