# Parseing xml and html in same project

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to parse in one project `XML` and `HTML` at the same time.

I tried this:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(fpath)
html_file = ET.parse(htmlpath)
```

and got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:.py", line 55, in 
>       html_file = ET.parse("htmlpath")
>     File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
>       tree.parse(source, parser)
>     File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
>       self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
>   xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity `&nbsp;`: line 690, column 78

Comment: The document referenced by `html_path` is not well-formed, and therefore it cannot be parsed as XML (ElementTree works with XML, not arbitrary HTML). The problem is that the document contains the `&nbsp;` entity reference without the corresponding declaration for the entity. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14744945/407651.

Comment: I suggest that you try the BeautifulSoup library: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/. You can use it for both XML and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The nbsp is a standard html5 entity. It may help to convert those to their unicode characters before running the xml parser. In python3.4+ you can use `html.unescape` for that.

```
from html import escape, unescape
textXML = re.sub("\\&\\w+\\;", lambda x: escape(unescape(x.group(0))), text)
```